# Why is ImageView alpha animation behaving unexpectedly?

Tags: android, android-animation, fadeout

I'm trying to fade out an `ImageView` using an animation.  The animation runs, fading out the `ImageView`, but then the image goes back to fully opaque.  Why does this happen?

```
private void fadeOutImage() {
   final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   imageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fadeout));
}
```

I tried setting the alpha to zero as below, but then the image never showed up period.  Why not?

```
private void fadeOutImage() {
   final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   imageView.setAlpha(0);
   imageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fadeout));
}
```

To get this to work, I had to create an `AnimationListener`, overload the `onAnimationEnd`, and set the alpha to be zero there.  Why?

```
  final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(id);
  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fadeout);
  animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

     @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { 
        imageView.setAlpha(255);
     }

     @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

     @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        imageView.setAlpha(0);
     }
  });
  imageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Animation XML:

```
<alpha
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

Comment: have you tried `imageView.clearAnimation();` when animation ends?

Comment: @MKJParekh No, why do you ask?

Comment: I've usually used ``Animation.setFillAfter(true)``. Don't know whether this is the best practise but has worked for me in most cases.

Comment: @harism solution is correct and most easiest way to persist effect of animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to fade out an `ImageView` using an animation.  The animation runs, fading out the `ImageView`, but then the image goes
>   back to fully opaque.  Why does this happen?

The animation's effects are *temporary*.  Once the animation has completed, the view returns to its state before the animation began.

> I tried setting the alpha to zero as below, but then the image never
>   showed up period.  Why not?

Though [apparently undocumented](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#alpha-element), the `fromAlpha` and `toAlpha` parameters appear to act in a *multiplicative* fashion.  100% of zero is still zero.  I verified this by starting the alpha to a very low value, and I could see that the animation caused the alpha to start at the low value and fade to transparent.

> To get this to work, I had to create an AnimationListener, overload
>   the onAnimationEnd, and set the alpha to be zero there. Why?

Since the animation's effects are temporary, you need to set the object to be transparent after the animation.  You also have to make sure you reset the object to be opaque before you start the animation.

It looks like you can use an [`ObjectAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) starting in API 11 to set the alpha (or any other property's) values directly using rather than multiplicatively.

Answer (score 7):

When you start an animation, it literally takes whatever the view currently looks like, animates it according to your supplied animation, but ***doesn't ever actually change the state of the view***.

This can get confusing, but in your first case, after the animation ends, the ImageView just goes back to whatever it looked like before the animation - in your case, the normal opaque.

In your second example, you are setting the alpha to zero *before* the animation starts, and so when the animation begins playing, the image is already invisible, and so it animates this invisible ImageView - which you can't see.

Therefore, the required sequence is to start the animation before changing the ImageView at all, let it play out, and then the moment the animation ends, change the state of the ImageView so that it disappears before it gets redrawn in it's original state. This is what overriding `onAnimationEnd()` does.

So, to recap, in the proper implementation, there are two things that affect how the ImageView gets drawn:

- The animation, which affects how the ImageView looks **only while the animation is playing**.
- The `imageView.setAlpha(0);` method call, to keep the image invisible **once the animation finishes**.

---

Note: to possibly increase performance, I'd suggest using

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

instead of `imageView.setAlpha(0);`

Comment: I assume you mean to say that it doesn't permanently change the state of the view.  Of course, the animation changes the state of the view at least temporarily.  I also assume you mean to use
`imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` instead of setting the alpha.  Before I accept your answer, I want

Comment: It temporarily overrides how it is drawn, but no, I don't believe any state(fields, properties, attributes, etc.) of the view is ever changed. EDIT: Unless, as harism suggested, you set Animation.setFillAfter(true), though I have heard this can have issues if the animation changes the size of the view.